# nginx SSL (SSL: error:14201044:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:internal error)

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've searched a bunch of questions to set the correct configuration for nginx SSL, but my EC2 website isn't online. Actually when It was only HTTP protocol (80), it was working fine.

**Steps I made**

1 - Set security group for ec2 opening traffic for all ipv4 to access 443 and 80 (ok)

[image: EC2 Security groups]

2 - Set `/etc/nginx/sites-avaiable` and `/etc/nginx/sites-eneabled` for only HTTP access, that was working fine (ok)

3 - Now started SSL process, creating crypto keys sudo `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.crt` (ok)

4 - Now I modified `default` file for both `/etc/nginx/sites-avaiable` and `/etc/nginx/sites-eneabled` to apply SSL on my website (???)

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com www.ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

  #Importing ssl
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
  ssl_certicate_key /etc/nginx/nginx-selfsigned.key;

  # front-end
  location / {
    root /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}

server {
 listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;

 server_name ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com www.ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com;

 return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

5 - Tested configuration `sudo nginx -t` and it's a ok configuration (ok)

6 - Restarted nginx `sudo systemctl restart nginx` (ok)

7 - Tested if the necessary ports are being listening `sudo netstat -plant | grep 80` `sudo netstat -plant | grep 443` and both are being listening (ok)

8 - It should work as everything looks great, so I tried to enter to website and for my surprise it's offline with error **"ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"**

https://ec2-23-22-52-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

9 - The unique thing that rest to check is the nginx error logs at  `/var/log/nginx/` , and there are this ERROR related to SSL

```
2022/04/07 19:24:25 [crit] 2453#2453: *77 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:14201044:SSL routines:tls_choose_sigalg:internal error) while SSL handshaking, client: 45.56.107.29, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

**Conclusion**

I don't know why SSL_do_handshake() failed. What I can do to fix this issue, anyone has a guess to solve this problem? Thanks a lot to stackoverflow community. You are great !!!

Comment: Try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1089684/nginx-cant-accept-tls-handshake-when-client-is-not-sending-tls-extensions

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @ApplePie brother I opted to use AWS SSL CERTIFICATE